# How to disaggregate a row?

Tags: r

I have a data table that looks like this:

```
cep3 <- structure(list(lat = c(-23.39429, -23.39988, -23.38233, -23.39009, -23.40135, -23.4019), lon = c(-46.3277, -46.30741, -46.30328, -46.31071, -46.32225, -46.32242), jobs = c(3, 1, 127, 2, 11, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
head(cep3)
```

I want to get n copies of each line (n = job), in a way that each line represents one job, but maintaining the lat/lon, so that when i plot it each line represents one point.

Is there a simple way to do it? I coudn't find any solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is `uncount`

```
library(tidyverse)
cep3 %>% 
    uncount(jobs)
```

If we need to keep the 'jobs' column, use `.remove = FALSE` (by default it is TRUE)

```
cep3 %>% 
   uncount(jobs, .remove = FALSE)
```